# How to write portable HTML forms regardless of processing script language?

Tags: php, asp.net, html

I have coded in PHP everytime I needed to do form processing for a website. When writing the HTML forms where there are arrays, I often use the square bracket notation:

```
<input type="text" name="fav_food[]"/>
<input type="text" name="fav_food[]"/>
<input type="text" name="fav_food[]"/>
```

I recently needed to write a test paper for interviewees from ASP background for form processing. So I went to research a bit on "POST array to ASP" and I find many articles describing the tips and tricks of the MVC model etc, which is overly complicated for my small brain and level of ASP knowledge.

This [blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for example shows how to do it for ASP:

```
<input type="text" name="fav_food"/>
<input type="text" name="fav_food"/>
<input type="text" name="fav_food"/>
```

Unfortunately, this will not work for PHP. This makes me wonder if there is an "action=" independant way of writing the HTML such that it will work regardless of the processing script langauge.

Also, how will ASP see the PHP form? Will it make into an array of "fav_food" or "fav_food[]" or fail?

Comment: The bracket hack is compensation for PHP's inherent design stupidities. most other web-processing languages will automatically build an array if a form field name is encountered multiple times while processing a submission. PHP by default will not, and simply overwrites previous values with 'newer' values, UNLESS you tell php to do an array instead, which is where the `[]` comes in. That being said, rarely do you EVER need to make a "generic" form that can be processed by any back-end language ever. usually the html was BUILT by that language to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Too keep it all independent, I'd say to add some javascript/jquery in between the HTML and the server side code. Collect the inputs with jQuery, format the JSON as desired and do a $.post() to the URL, be it PHP or ASP, and handle the JSON in the scripting code.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC also supports the square bracket notation (although slightly differently). The best source on the topic: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

If you need to reuse the HTML forms you will have to adjust the server side processing. ASP.NET MVC has a very flexible binding solution that can be used to adapt to any kind of forms. You can also do some extra processing in PHP.